Get f(z) from component functions u(x, y), v(x, y)
I'm following Schaum's Outline Series on Complex analysis (great book). There's a solution to problem 3.8 that i don't understand. Given:
$$ 
f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\\
u(x,y)=e^{-x}(x\sin y - y\cos y)\\
v(x,y)=e^{-x}(y\sin y + x\cos y)
$$
The solution says: Putting y=0 we've got $f(x)=u(x,0)+iv(x,0)$, so substituting x by z this leaves:
$$ f(z)=u(z,0)+iv(z,0)=ize^{-z} $$
I don't get the technique: If z is real, the expression applies, of course. Why does it hold when z is not real too?
Thanks.

I'm not sure where you're stuck. It's clear that the real part of $ize^{-z}$ is the given $u$ and the imaginary part is the given $v$. It seems to me that the technique provides us with a good guess and that we must then check out the the guess works.

You are missing something important, that $f$ is analytic. See problem 3.7

We know from problem 3.7 (b) that
\begin{align*}
f(z)=f(x+iy)&=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\\
u(x,y)&=e^{-x}(x\sin y - y\cos y)\tag{1}\\
v(x,y)&=e^{-x}(y\sin y + x\cos y)
\end{align*}
is an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}$. We know from the derivation in problem 3.8 (Method 1) that $f$ has also a representation
\begin{align*}
f(z)=ize^{-z}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
as analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$.
Thanks to the identity theorem we conclude these representations are equal on $\mathbb{C}$.
I couldn't find the identity theorem in Schaum's book, but you can take a look at problems 10.1 and 10.2, where this topic is considered in the context of analytic continuation.
